# Gradle not allocating enough RAM

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make a mod in forge 1.16.5 using gradle. I am also using Intelij Idea for my IDE. When I do runClient gradle only gives me 257 MB of ram.

I tried Chat GPT and none of its answers worked. I tried googleing it and it told me to change my JVM args and I was still having issues.

ORIGINAL ERROR
`[15:59:07] [Render thread/FATAL] [minecraft/Minecraft]: Out of memory`

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

After adding `jvmArgs "-Xms2g", "-Xmx2g"` to build.gradle
`Execution failed for task ':runClient'.`

`> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

I tried 1G ram insted
`java.io.IOException: Could not load image: Out of memory`

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Image is not allocated.`

Comment: How much free memory does your system have? How did you select those values? What is the architecture of your system?

Comment: My system is 64 bit I have 16 gb ram and at the time had 5 gb free

Comment: You are using a 32 bits Java It is possible that you need to use a 64 bit Java to be able to access enough available free memory.